# TIdTCPServer not working after upgrading to C++Builder 11

Tags: c++builder, indy

The following code worked in C++Builder 10.3 Rio to stream a file across the network. After upgrading to C++Builder 11 Alexandria, `fileStreamerExecute()` never gets called. The file does get created at path, but is zero length and is in use, so any attempt to open the file fails. I'm guessing some changes occurred with Indy and so some changes are required in my code?

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Tdata::stream_file(String path, Tstream_dir direction)
{
  _stream_path = path;
  _stream_dir = direction;
  if (_fs)
    delete _fs;
  if (_stream_dir == sdIn)
    _fs = new TFileStream(_stream_path, fmCreate | fmShareDenyNone);
  else
    _fs = new TFileStream(_stream_path, fmOpenRead | fmShareDenyNone);
  fileStreamer->DefaultPort = 9965;
  fileStreamer->Active = true;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall Tdata::fileStreamerExecute(TIdContext *AContext)
{
  if (_stream_dir == sdIn)
  {
    try
    {
      _fs->Position = 0;
      AContext->Connection->IOHandler->ReadStream(_fs, -1, true);
    }
    __finally
    {
        delete _fs;
        _fs = 0;
    }
    AContext->Connection->Disconnect();
  }
  else
  {
    try
    {
      AContext->Connection->IOHandler->Write(_fs);
    }
    __finally
    {
        delete _fs;
        _fs = 0;
    }
    AContext->Connection->Disconnect();
  }  
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TstartForm::TstartForm(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner)
{
  char hostname[256];
  String host_ip = "";
  _progressForm = 0;
  if (gethostname(hostname, 256) == 0) {
    hostent *host = gethostbyname(hostname);
    if (host) {
      char *addr = host->h_addr;
      if (addr) {
        host_ip = String(inet_ntoa(*(in_addr*) addr));
        // returns "192.168.180.1" from VMWare network adaptor
        // hard code to correct value for testing
        host_ip = "192.168.1.226"; 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** updated to get the local IP like this instead, and now things are working:

```cpp
__fastcall TstartForm::TstartForm(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner)
{
  _progressForm = 0;
  String host_ip = L"";
  TIdStackWindows* id_stack = new TIdStackWindows;
  if (id_stack) {
    host_ip = id_stack->LocalAddress;
    delete id_stack;
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** updated to get the local IP per Remy's Recommendation

```cpp
__fastcall TstartForm::TstartForm(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner)
{
  _progressForm = 0;
  String host_ip = L"";
  TIdStack::IncUsage();
  host_ip = GStack->LocalAddress;
  TIdStack::DecUsage();
  sm->_this_computer_id = host_ip;
}
```

Comment: "*after upgrading to C++Builder 11 Alexandria, `fileStreamerExecute` never gets called*" - did you verify that `fileStreamerExecute()` is actually being assigned to the `TIdTCPServer::OnExecute` event at runtime? Or that a client is actually connecting to your server? "*the file does get created at path*" - sure, because you are creating the file before activating the server. But you have provided no info about what happens while the server is active to troubleshoot with...

Comment: ... "*but is zero length*" - sure, if nothing ever writes to it. "*and is in use, the attempt to open the file fails*" - because your code is leaving the file open. "*I'm guessing some changes occurred with Indy and some changes are required?*" - No changes have been made to Indy between Rio and Alexandria that would account for this issue.

Comment: Also, you have a mismatch between your `Write(fs)` and `ReadStream(fs)` calls.  You are telling `Write()` to send the file stream WITHOUT sending its length beforehand. But you are telling `ReadStream()` to expect a length in front of the stream data.  Does your client code account for this descrepency?

Comment: I'm using Indy to communicate with Poco and I think this file streaming problem is secondary to something more fundamental.  I have a TIdTCPClient that has and still works fine, this is the main communication channel between the C++Builder client and Poco server. I also have several TIdTCPServer that I use for this file streaming but also for what I call "back channel" communication, these are just not connecting, they time out.  They do however work if the server and client are running on the same computer, not a firewall issue, works fine under Rio.

Comment: You didn't really address my questions/concerns. What have you done so far to try to debug this issue? There have been no fundamental changes to Indy between Rio and Alexandria that would account for what you are seeing, so there has to be something else going on that you have not accounted for yet.

Comment: Turns out this had nothing to do with Indy, I added to the code what I'm using to get the IP address of the computer, it's returning the address of a VMWare network adapter, obviously what I'm doing is no good but it worked OK with Rio and Sydney.

Comment: What does that code have to do with `TIdTCPServer` not working? In any case, Indy's `TIdStack` class has a `GetLocalAddressList()` method (and `LocalAddress/es` properties) for retrieving the local computer's IPs.

Comment: The client was being asked to connect to an IP where no server was listening, changed the code to use TIdStackWindows::LocalAddress which does return the correct IP.

Comment: if the client and server are on the same machine, why not just use `localhost`/`127.0.0.1`? In any case, the correct usage of `TIdStack` would be: `TIdStack::IncUsage(); host_ip = GStack->LocalAddress; TIdStack::DecUsage();`

Comment: Changed the code per your recommendation.  I need to know the real IP address, I need to tell the Poco server to connect it's "back channel" to that address.  Yes local host would technically work when on the same machine but there are implementation reasons why I want the parties to be oblivious that the connection is local if it is.